# How I get the "university name" from LinkedIn APIs?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

- I used Android LinkedIn SDK into my application but I got very few data like name, username, email Id, which is very basic information but actually, I want University name, user's company name etc..
- Please guide how can I get the above details or is there any special permission required from the LinkedIn side?

  I tried a demo of LinkedIn and I get the basic information like name, email id, profile link etc.. but don't know how I can get the university/college name etc.. details from it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you either need one of these two permissions when requesting the profile API:

> **r_basicprofile**    Required to retrieve name, photo, headline, and current positions for the authenticated user.
>
> **r_fullprofile** Required to retrieve full profile for authenticated user.

From the [profile api docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context)